# success callback handler not called in jquery

Tags: jquery, padrino

I am working on a `Padrino app` running on my `local server(localhost:3000)`. I am exposing a get call /location which is returning a json response. I am hitting this API from the javascript code written separately. Here is what i am writing:

```
$.get("http://localhost:3000/location", function(data) {    
    alert("Inside callback" + data); 
});
```

(PS : using `jquery 1.9.1`, tried getJSON also) The http end point is getting hit and returning sucess code 200 with json response but the success call back handler is not being called in the javascript. Why is that happening? Any way to do so?

Comment: If you want to get JSON use `$.getJSON` instead of `$.get`. (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an ) at the end, like:

```
$.get("http://localhost:3000/location", function(data) {    
alert("Inside callback" + data); 
});
```

For JSON you might want to consider using getJSON instead, and catch the error if something went wrong.

You can also use the low-level ajax call and check if there was an error:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/location',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data){ 
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function(request,error) {
        alert(request.responseText); 
    }
});
```

Comment: tried getJSON also and missing ) is a typo. Pardon me for ... any other solution?

Comment: what is the server returning exactly? It might be that it's not returning correct reponse.

Comment: server is returning 200 ok response... which means that it is hitting it correctly but getting nothing in the javascript

Comment: see my edited response (use ajax call and be sure you don't get an error back)

Comment: error is not clear... its saying woops!object Object] when i am doing alert('woops!' +data)... already tried these things.

Comment: try the responseText property

Answer (score 0):

Try it like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("http://localhost:3000/location", function(data) {    
        alert("Inside callback" + data); 
    });// here you are missed closed parenthesis ')'
});
```

Comment: ')' is a typo. Sorry for that... any other solution?

Comment: Try my answer once, I have changed.

Comment: hey Rohan... i am also doing exactly that.... able to hit the http end and gettong 200 success response(verified using firebug) but getting nothing in the response.(havn't included 1st line in my question but i am doing it)

Comment: Check in `console` waht is the `response` you `get`?

Comment: getting the headers but response is empty... that's the problem

Comment: @AnirudhGupta yes that's the problem, do you want to send data like `json`?

Comment: It's hitting the backend api but the success call back handler is not being called in the javascript. why is that so? It should return the JSON response in javascript also

Comment: If you want that `data` should return as `json` then use `json` as `third` `parameter` in `$.get` function Read http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/